# How to display colorful emoji on Intellij 2022?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, output, emoji

I was using a Mac and I could display emoji with colours, now back on Windows I can't anymore.
I really tried many solutions like:

- trying different fonts
- using google noto font
- changing fallback font
- changing utf encoding
- tick or untick the "only monospaced fonts"

I still can't display emoji with colours but only in Monochrome in my console output.

[image: output example monochrome]

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: [This would be worth a read](https://www.powershellcenter.com/2021/02/19/add-emojis-to-powershell-output/) I should think.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) where the rendering has been adjusted, so all the emojis are colorful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately the output is the same..should I set something in particular?

Comment: Where do you see them?

Comment: I don't see them, that's the problem. I try to print them for example "\uD83D\uDE42" but they're always gray..

Comment: I mean what is the tool window you are looking at? Is it terminal, markdown preview, code editor, or something else?

Comment: Oh! Sorry I see, it's the terminal window of IntelliJ, std-output.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Appearance - Use custom font ->
I change to Apple Color Emoji.

I check log tab and look colorful emoji.